# Overflow in ActionMode Callback menu causes TextView to lose focus

Tags: android, textview, android-actionmode

I have a `TextView` element which has an `ActionMode Callback` associated with it. On long-clicking a word, the `ActionMode` activates a menu on the action bar. Some of the menu options are presented in an overflow menu on devices with smaller screens.

On some devices, clicking on the overflow button causes the `TextView` to lose focus and the text selection to automatically clear. I have read that this is a bug in the framework. Given that the application supports only devices beyond Android 4.0, my question(s):

1. How do I detect if some of the menu items will be presented in the overflow menu at runtime?
2. How do I prevent the `TextView` from losing focus?
3. Some of the devices (Samsung etc.) do not show this feature. Is this then really a framework bug?
4. If the overflow menu and resulting loss of focus is something I am going to have to contend with, is there an alternative?

Comment: Just run into this myself on android 5 (api 21) using appcompat. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @svn: No i did not.